# Why is $y\sim\mathcal{N}(Xβ,\sigma^{2} I_n)$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Why is $y\sim\mathcal{N}(Xβ,\sigma^{2} I_n)$? 
(i.e. $\varepsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2} I_n)$)

How can I obtain $y\sim\mathcal{N}(Xβ,\sigma^{2} I_n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a constant $X\beta$ to a normally distributed random variable is again normal.

The mean of the $y = X\beta + \epsilon$ is:
$$E(y) = E(X\beta + \epsilon) = E(X\beta) + E(\epsilon) = X\beta + 0 = X\beta$$
and the variance is 
$$\operatorname{var} (y) = E(y -X\beta)(y -X\beta)^T = E(\epsilon \epsilon^T) = \operatorname{var} (\epsilon) = \sigma^2 I$$
We conclude that 
$$y \sim N(X \beta, \sigma^2 I)$$

Comment: Hi, why is the variance of y equal to (y−Xβ)? should't it be Xβ+ϵ?

Comment: so by definition: $$\operatorname{var} (y) = E(y - E(y))(y-E(y))^T$$

Comment: Hi again, I am a follow up question. How do you know var(y) is a vector rather than a variable? Since the definition you provided is for random vector. Thanks ! @Ahmad Bazzi

Comment: Hi @MathAvengers, assuming it to be a vector if it were a scalar is okay, because:
$$\operatorname{var} (y) = E(y - E(y))(y-E(y))^T=E( y-E(y))^2$$ for scalar $y$.

Comment: @Admad Bazzi , what about assuming a vector as a scalar, is that okay? Thank you so much !!!

Comment: what do you mean by "assuming a vector as a scalar," ?

Comment: You stated that it's okay to assume a scalar to be a vector, what about the converse ?

Comment: In linear algebra, a scalar is a $1 \times 1$ vector. What can you say about "seeing a vector as a scalar" ? So when you use $E( y-E(y))^2$ for vectors, it does not make sense because there is no such thing as $y^2$ where $y$ is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The variance will not change if you add a constant, i.e $Var(X+c)=Var(X)$, here $X\beta$ is a constant

The formula is :

$Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2} I_n)$